Openstack ip availability include link-local in calculation
I have a question. Is this considered a bug? I have a user who add a link-local IP address as part of their IP subnet and does not expect it to calculate with the user/available IP:
Example:
[root@vhi-node1 ~]# openstack --insecure ip availability list
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Network ID                           | Network Name | Total IPs | Used IPs |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 9566478f-e278-4294-a8c0-5d02a095627d | lattafa_hq   |    131576 |        6 |

Used Ip also calculate link-local 169.254.xx address:
[root@vhi-node1 ~]# openstack --insecure ip availability show lattafa_hq
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                  | Value                                                                                                                                       
|
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id                     | 9566478f-e278-4294-a8c0-5d02a095627d                                                                                                        
|
| name                   | None                                                                                                                                        
|
| network_id             | 9566478f-e278-4294-a8c0-5d02a095627d                                                                                                        
|
| network_name           | lattafa_hq                                                                                                                                  
|
| project_id             | 0c8a73e5b34b40eca79200f630ac6e14                                                                                                            
|
| subnet_ip_availability | cidr='10.4.0.0/16', ip_version='4', subnet_id='03425964-7683-4344- 
8543-cfc27887bdb7', subnet_name='test', total_ips='65533', used_ips='2'   |
|                        | cidr='169.254.32.0/23', ip_version='4', subnet_id='2bf248de-e487- 
40de-833e-bc4cc427878e', subnet_name='test', total_ips='509', used_ips='2' |
|                        | cidr='10.3.0.0/16', ip_version='4', subnet_id='8e25cbda-675f-4439- 
a1f2-51d5aa4b6de5', subnet_name='', total_ips='65534', used_ips='2'       |
| total_ips              | 131576                                                                                                                                      
|
| used_ips               | 6                                                                                                                                           
|

